# Algebraicity of the completion of a field?  Finiteness?

Tags: fields, mg.metric-geometry

At the end of my 8410 class today (see [http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/MATH8410.html](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/MATH8410.html) if you care), one of my students asked me the following very interesting question:

Let $(K,|\ |)$ be a [normed field](http://eom.springer.de/n/n067360.htm), with completion $(\hat{K},| \ |)$.  Suppose $\hat{K}$ is algebraic over $K$.  Must we then have $\hat{K} = K$?

As I have mentioned here before, I feel very lucky to be getting such penetrating questions.  This one I was not able to answer on the spot, although I remarked that it is true in all of the most familiar examples and that the (possible) lack of algebraicity of the completion is a key motivation for considering the **Henselization** instead.

**Edit**: the answer is **no**, as I have just heard from one of my students.  I have encouraged him to come to this site and register the answer.

To make the question more interesting, suppose we ask whether $\hat{K}/K$ can be finite and nontrivial?

Comment: If $\hat K/K$ is finite then $K$ is a closed $K$-subvector space of $\hat K$, for it is a finite dimensional subspace, so in particular  $K$ is complete, no?

Comment: I was thinking along these lines.  But unlike in the case of usual Banach spaces we don't have a complete field "at the bottom", so is it obvious that a finite-dimensional subspace is closed?

Comment: A finite dimensional $K$-subspace is closed, because it is the kernel of a linear map to some other space, I guess.

Comment: I can't tell whether you are speculating or answering.  If the latter, could you say a little more?

Comment: Sorry :) If $V$ is a subspace of a finite dimensional $K$-vector space $W$, then it is the kernel of a $K$-linear map $\phi:W\to U$ to some other vector space $U$. Since every space in sight is finite dimensional the map $\phi$ is continuous, so $V$ is closed in $W$.

Comment: I'm still unconvinced.  If the ground field is complete, then finite dimensional linear maps are automatically continuous.  I am worried that this is not true in general.  

Comment: Mariano's right according to wikipedia.  Linear transformations between finite dimensional TVS's are forced to be continuous.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous_linear_map has a proof for normed spaces, which is still enough for his claim, but another page said it was true for arbitrary TV Spaces.

Comment: But on this wikipedia page, "normed space" means normed space over the real or complex numbers, both complete fields.  I'm not trying to be argumentative: I really don't know the answer myself (nor have I given myself a good chance to think about it; that's a little later in my course preparation), but I have concerns that the issue is more subtle than it appears.  Can you give a reference that works with vector spaces over an arbitrary (not necessarily complete!) normed field?

Comment: OK, here's a counterexample to the automatic continuity claim: consider Q(\sqrt{2}) as a vector space over Q with the standard Archimedean norm.  There are two ways to extend this norm to Q(\sqrt{2}), differing by Galois conjugation.  Therefore Galois conjugation is a Q-linear map which is not continuous for either norm.  More plainly, the sequence (\sqrt{2}-1)^n converges to zero in one topology but not the other.  

Comment: I read that wikipedia page fairly closely, and I'm pretty sure that the assumption is not used.  The only thing it seems like they might be using is an assumption of characteristic 0?.  Anyway, I know that Bourbaki has a very general treatment of topological vector spaces in volume 5, called topological vector spaces. I think there are copies on the internet floating around in French as Espaces  Vectorielles Topologiques.  I also saw a copy of "Topological Vector Spaces" by Grothendieck floating around.  

Comment: @Harry: please see Exercise 1.4 of http://math.uga.edu/~pete/8410Chapter1.pdf.

Comment: The proof that finite-dimensional subspace is closed is essentially that it is complete, therefore closed.  But of course completeness of the f.d. subspace requires completeness of the field.  See the Q(\sqrt{2}) counterexample.  In fact there are more norms than just the two listed (compatible with the usual archimedean norm on Q itself).

Comment: Given a valued field $K$ and a finite dimensional vector space $V$, the topology on $V$ is the one it gets by choosing a basis, using it to construct an $K$-linear isomorphism $V\cong K^n$, and then transporting the product topology from $K^n$ to $V$, right?

Comment: If so, then clearly a hyperplane in $V$ is closed, for the coordinate hyperplanes in $K^n$ are closed. Since every subspace of $V$ is the intersection of the hyperplanes that contain it, we can then conclude that every such subspace is closed. This is what I had in mind above. 

Comment: @Mariano: it is a theorem that if K is complete, the only topology on a finite dimensional vector space is the product topology.  This does not hold in general: in my counterexample above, you can see that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ in each of the two topologies I gave, so neither is the product topology.  

Comment: The link to `eom.springer.de` is broken, but the article can now be found at https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Norm_on_a_field.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(I'll delete this if your student came up with the same answer.)

Choose a ring-theoretic automorphism of the complex numbers that doesn't fix the reals (I'm pretty sure any nontrivial automorphism other than complex conjugation will work), and consider the image of the reals in it.  <strike>A similar trick should work for any real closed field with transcendence degree at least 1 over Q.</strike>  I'm not sure what I was thinking with the last sentence, but it's clearly false.

However, a similar trick should work for any finite Galois extension of complete normed fields such that the overfield has a discontinuous automorphism.  For example, if we hit $\mathbb{C}((t))$ with some discontinuous non-$\mathbb{C}$-linear automorphism, I think the subfield $\mathbb{C}((t^3))$ is sent to a dense subfield.

Comment: My (apparently MO-shy) student came up with the example of a subextension L of R/Q such that L/Q is purely transcendental and R/L is (certainly nontrivial) algebraic.  As I pointed out in today's problem session, the Artin-Schreier theorem guarantees that R/L is infinite, so this does not answer the second question.  In fact, your very nice answer to the second question prompts a third question: can we have $2 < [\hat{K}:K] < \infty$?

Comment: Thanks again, Scott.  Your new example sounds reasonable; I'll have to think about it.  Now what about $[\hat{K}:K] \geq 4$?  (Just kidding.)  

Comment: Ah, I see, it's way easier than what I wrote below, isn't it?  If an automorphism of C doesn't fix the reals, then the image of R contains a non-real z (R has no nontrivial automorphisms, so if an automorphism doesn't fix the reals then it doesn't preserve them), and then the Q-vector-subspace of the image generated by 1 and z is dense, so the whole image is dense.

Comment: @Dave: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 8):

I had to think for a while to understand Scott's answer (or at least, what I suspect he meant by his answer), and in the end there were enough details to sort out that I thought they were worth posting.  It ended up being too long to post as a comment, so here it is as a separate answer.  Unless it's all nonsense, of course....

Let {$x_{\alpha}$} be a transcendence basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $L$ be the intermediate field that they generate, so that $\mathbb{C}$ is the algebraic closure of $L$ in $\mathbb{C}$.   Take also a collection of open disks $D_{\alpha}$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that any collection of points $y_{\alpha} \in D_{\alpha}$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$ in the usual topology.  Now for each $\alpha$, take $x_\alpha$ and multiply it by an appropriate root of unity and a rational number so that the result $y_\alpha$ lies in $D_\alpha$.  The collection {$y_{\alpha}$} is still algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, because a dependence gives an algebraic dependence of {$x_\alpha$} over some finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, which implies the existence of an algebraic dependence over $\mathbb{Q}$ as well.

So there exists $\sigma : L \to \mathbb{C}$ sending $x_{\alpha} \mapsto y_{\alpha}$.  Now by the usual fact that field embeddings into algebraically closed fields can be extended across algebraic extensions, $\sigma$ extends to a map $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$.  But note that by construction $\sigma$ is surjective!  The image contains each $y_\alpha$, and it contains all the roots of unity, so it contains all the $x_\alpha$'s; thus the image is an algebraic closure of $L$ in $\mathbb{C}$, hence all of $\mathbb{C}$.

In particular $\mathbb{C}$ is a quadratic extension of $\sigma(\mathbb{R})$, obtained by adjoining $\sigma(i)$.  But finally $\sigma(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$ since its image contains all the $y_\alpha$'s, and so giving $\sigma(\mathbb{R})$ the norm induced from the usual norm on $\mathbb{C}$, we get a normed field $\sigma(\mathbb{R})$ whose completion is exactly $\mathbb{C}$, i.e., a quadratic extension of it.  Thus the answer to your second question actually yes.

Comment: +1 to you too, Dave.  

Comment: Does this answer depend on the axiom of choice?

Comment: Boy oh boy, does it ever!  But probably Scott's does too, since you need to construct non-obvious automorphisms of C?

Comment: Yes, certainly.  The entire theory of transcendental field extensions as we know it depends heavily on AC.  It is consistent with ZF that the only automorphisms of the complex numbers are the identity and complex conjugation.  I've used Zorn's Lemma several times in my lectures already.