# Can the algebraic closure of a complete field be complete and of infinite degree?

Tags: fields, mg.metric-geometry, valuation-theory

Yes, this is yet another "foundational" question in valuation theory.

Here's the background: it is a well known classical fact that the dimension (in the purely algebraic sense) of a real Banach space cannot be countably infinite.  The proof is a simple application of the Baire Category Theorem: see e.g. [PlanetMath](https://planetmath.org/BanachSpacesOfInfiniteDimensionDoNotHaveACountableHamelBasis).

Suppose now that $(K,| \ |)$ is a complete non-Archimedean (**edit**: nontrivial) normed field.  One has the notion of a $K$-Banach space, and the Baire Category Theorem argument works verbatim to show that such a thing cannot have countably infinite $K$-dimension.

Now let $\overline{K}$ be an algebraic closure of $K$.  Then $\overline{K}$, by virtue of being a direct limit of finite-dimensional normed spaces over the complete field $K$, has a canonical topology, and indeed a unique multiplicative norm which extends $|\ |$ on $K$.

My question is: does there exist a complete normed field $(K, | \ |)$ such that:

1. $[\overline{K}:K] = \infty$ and
2. $\overline{K}$ is complete with respect to its norm?

As with [a previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13346/algebraicity-of-the-completion-of-a-field-finiteness), it is not too hard to see that this does not happen in the most familiar cases.  Indeed, by the above considerations this can only happen if $[\overline{K}:K]$ is uncountable.  But $[\overline{K}:K]$ will be countable if $K$ has a countable dense subfield $F$ [to be absolutely safe, let me also require that $F$ is perfect].  Indeed, the algebraic closure of any infinite field has the same cardinality of the field, so $\overline{F}$ can be obtained by adjoining roots of a countable collection of separable polynomials $P_i(t) \in F[t]$.  It follows from [Krasner's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krasner%27s_lemma) that by adjoining to $K$ the roots of these polynomials one gets $\overline{K}$.

What about the general case?

Comment: yes: let K be the rationals and |.| the trivial norm (|0|=0, |x|=1 otherwise).

Comment: More helpfully: if the norm is (non-trivial and) *discrete* then probably an easy argument (analogous to one of the proofs that Q_p-bar isn't complete) gives that it can't happen. For the norm on K-bar won't be discrete (take roots of a uniformiser pi of K) so you can build some awkward x in the completion of K-bar with v(x)=1, v(x-pi)=3.5, v((x-pi)^2-pi^7)=10!+1/3 and so on and so on, meaning that the valuation on K(x) induced by K contains numbers with arbitrarily large denominator, so K(x) can't be discrete, so x can't be algebraic over K.

Comment: See the slightly related question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/389220/454

Comment: While cleaning up the PlanetMath link, I tried to guess what previous question you might have meant; based on your recent-as-of-then questions, [Algebraicity of the completion of a field? Finiteness?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13346/algebraicity-of-the-completion-of-a-field-finiteness) seemed most likely.  I hope that was correct; if not, please feel free to revert (or, even better, to replace with a link to the correct question).

Comment: @Glorfindel, would it be appropriate to make a MMO post, to go with [Is it time to replace links to the UCDavis arXiv frontend?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5124/is-it-time-to-replace-links-to-the-ucdavis-arxiv-frontend), to invite other users to join your crusade to fix PlanetMath links?  (And, thanks!)

Comment: @LSpice [Martin Sleziak already started one on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375121/295232), since this affects the entire network. For my script, it's a simple find & replace, the UCDavis case is way more complex. I don't think we want to bump [40 questions](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3A%22planetmath.org%2Fencyclopedia%22) at once, so I scheduled the script to run once every three days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No,  there exists no such field (with a non-trivial norm).  A proof can be found in Bosch, Güntzer, Remmert: Non-Archimedean Analysis, Lemma 1, Section 3.4.3.

Comment: So in fact the proof is the same idea as the one in my comment above. Replace "has valuation n+1/d" by "is close to an element that generates an extension of K of dgree d" and then use Krasner's Lemma.

Comment: @KevinBuzzard's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14977/can-the-algebraic-closure-of-a-complete-field-be-complete-and-of-infinite-degree#comment26854_14977) referenced [above](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14977/can-the-algebraic-closure-of-a-complete-field-be-complete-and-of-infinite-degree#comment26865_14981).