# Metric completion of an algebraically closed field is algebraically closed?

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups, fields

> Let $F$ be a complete metric topological field.  Suppose there is a subfield $F_1 \subset F$, algebraically closed and topoolgically dense in $F$.  Must $F$ itself be algebraically closed?

We can find this in the literature in case $F$ is a valued field.

I asked it this way, rather than just starting with a metric algebraically closed field and taking its completion.  As Laurent Moret-Bailly remarked in a comment [HERE](https://mathoverflow.net/q/383464/454), the metric completion of a metric topological field need not even be a field.

Comment: This is an excellent question. I wanted to post it myself a while ago, but first I wanted to make sure that such a field - completely metrizable, but not topologically isomorphic to a valued field - exists at all. This is why I posted the following question: 
https://mathoverflow.net/q/238809/89334

Comment: When you say "complete metric", do you assume the metric and the field topology define the same uniform structure? Or even that the metric is translation-invariant?

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Yes, I assume a translation-invariant metric, so that the metric topology is the uniform topology.

Comment: Is there a counterexample without the metric restriction?

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Here is a stupid example, regarding topological fields. Take $F=\bar{\mathbb{Q}}(\pi)\subset \mathbb{C}$ with the induced topology and $F_1=\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$. This shows that you better ask for some sort of completeness.

Comment: @UriBader: Of course, but complete does not mean metric.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Sure, I was just pointing at a triviality. The analogue question regarding fields which are complete wrt to the additive group uniformity makes perfects sense to me.